# cannot pass a javascript object to php via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I've created a new array in javascript and I'm adding values to it indexes from a function an then passing the array to the ajaxCall function were I try to convert it to json and send it to a php file via ajax, but the variable json is allways empty. I've been reading a lot about how to send javascript objects json_encoded via ajax and looks like this is the way to do it, but obviously I haven't readed enought or there is something I've been missing. Anycase I'm newbie in javascript and any help would be apreciated.

```
    function createArray()
    {
        var advancedFormVars = new Array();
        advancedFormVars['checkbox1'] = document.getElementById('OfferID').value;  
        advancedFormVars['checkbox2'] =document.getElementById('offerName').value;

    AjaxCall(advancedFormVars);
    }
    function AjaxCall(advancedFormVars){
    var json = new Array();
    json = JSON.stringify(advancedFormVars); //in debuger it shows me this as content of json variable--> [] but advancedFormVars is not empty

$.ajax({
        url : 'AL_loadForm.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            json : json 
        },
        dataType:'json',
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
    }
...
```

Comment: An associative array in PHP would be an `object` in JavaScript. Change `advancedFormVars` to -> `var advancedFormVars = {};`

Comment: you mean to replace var advancedFormVars = new Array(); to var advancedFormVars = {};  ??

Comment: Yes. `var json = new Array();` is not needed btw. as you're overwriting the array with the result of `JSON.stringify()` in the next line. Remove the line and add the `var ` to the next line -> `var json = JSON.stringify(...);`

Comment: Thanks a lot Andreas you are the boss!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use your array as a hash, so the values are not being set..

**Instead of setting**

`var advancedFormVars = new Array();`

**Try setting**

`var advancedFormVars = {};`

Example

**JS:**

```
var advancedFormVars = {};
advancedFormVars['checkbox1'] = 'valueA';
advancedFormVars['checkbox2'] = 'valueB';

var json = JSON.stringify(advancedFormVars);

console.log(json); //{"checkbox1":"valueA","checkbox2":"valueB"}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$json = '{"checkbox1":"valueA","checkbox2":"valueB"}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj);
/*
    object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
      ["checkbox1"]=>
        string(6) "valueA"
      ["checkbox2"]=>
        string(6) "valueB"
    }
*/
?>
```

Comment: and the way of assignment is the same? will this work as well ---> advancedFormVars['checkbox1'] = document.getElementById('OfferID').value;??

Comment: @user3033437 Yes. Have a look at [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and [Working with object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) - (to prevent any confusion when reading the links^^: `var foo = new Object()` is the same as `var foo = {}`)

Answer (score 0):

If all you have are two smaller arguments, I'd keep it simple and make an http get request. Encode your arguments if neccessary.

```
var url = "http://wherever.com/something.php?arg1=";
url += document.getElementById('OfferID').value;
url += "&arg2=" + document.getElementById('offerName').value;
httpGetAsync(url, returnMethod);

function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
{
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
        callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
}
xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: nop, this is only for the example code, I have a lot of arguments, thats why I'm using an array