# How to send javascript object to php via ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I looked at some other questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937144/sending-javascript-object-to-php-via-ajax) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762688/cannot-pass-a-javascript-object-to-php-via-ajax), but it does not me help me solve my problem. When I console-log my data, I get this:

```
Object["row_LM#00000010", "row_LM#00000002", "row_LM#00000009", "row_LM#00000008"]
```

How can I get this in php as a key value pair like row_ : LM#00000010, row_LM#00000002, row_LM#00000009,LM#00000008, so that I can loop each value? I tried JSON.stringify(), I got `TypeError: cyclic object value`

Here's what I have tried:

```
            $.ajax({
                  type:'POST',
                  url:'delinvoices.php',
                 data:{del_id:JSON.stringify(deleteInvoice)},
                success: function(data){
                     //other codes
                }
            });
```

The console.log of `deleteInvoice` gave me:

```
Object["row_LM#00000010", "row_LM#00000002", "row_LM#00000009", "row_LM#00000008"]
```

The base data comes from datatable

```
var deleteInvoice = dt.rows( { selected: true } ).ids();
```

Please help.

Comment: The best way would be to write some code and then post it in your question as an [mcve] so you will get help instead of down votes

Comment: There still isn't enough information here to really help. It LOOKS like you have a simple array. Where's the base data? What does it look like? I'd be curious to see what deleteInvoice looks like BEFORE the stringify.

Comment: Not really seeing what you're expecting in php.  It looks like just 1 key value pair, with the key being `row_` and the value being `LM#00000010, row_LM#00000002, row_LM#00000009,LM#00000008`

Comment: The base data comes from datatable. `var deleteInvoice = dt.rows( { selected: true } ).ids();`

Comment: @Tibrogargan, I thought I would get the data using $_POST['del_id'] which then could be looped.

Comment: You say you want key value pairs - which are the keys,and which are the values? Your console.log is showing an array that would be numerically indexed. Objects should be contained in {}, arrays are in [].

What does console.log(deleteInvoice); give you?

Comment: According to this page (https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30848/trying-to-get-get-the-row-ids-using-rows-ids), you are getting a dataTables object instance. To get an array, you'd do this: table.rows( { selected: true } ).ids().toArray(); It might help to simplify what you're working with, the dataTables object might be what's going cyclic on you.

Comment: @Rob Wood, In fact, one key which contains comma separated values.

Comment: Ok, so you just have an array. So try dt.rows( { selected: true } ).ids().toArray() when you assign to deleteInvoice,and then you should have a simple array that won't cause so many problems, rather than a dataTables object.

Comment: @RobWood, that's nice. Your comment answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. Made the comment an answer so you can mark it as correct. =}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this page (https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30848/trying-to-get-get-the-row-ids-using-rows-ids), you are getting a dataTables object instance. To get an array, you'd do this:

```
table.rows( { selected: true } ).ids().toArray();
```

It might help to simplify what you're working with, the dataTables object might be what's going cyclic on you.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for giving me the points. Like 75% or more of people never bother, or I'd have 1,000 reputation points rather than under 300. =}